# Train LSTM on days and predict on weeks

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I am training a LSTM to predict requests. The input data is split by day, like so:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start = dt.date(day=1, month=1, year=2022)
end = dt.date(day=8, month=1, year=2022)
training_data = pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3], index=np.arange(start, end))

training_data
2022-01-01  0
2022-01-02  0
2022-01-03  1
2022-01-04  0
2022-01-05  0
2022-01-06  2
2022-01-07  3
```

However, for my use case, I only need to predict weekly number of requests, not daily. So in this case, I would only need to predict 6 requests for the week starting on 2022-01-01.

I understand that I could resample the training data to also be on a weekly basis. But would it be possible to train on data split up by day and predict on weeks? My hypothesis is that the daily timesteps might help the model training, but my worry is that the alternate timescale here might mess up the training of the LSTM. I also am not sure exactly how normalization would work.